# Why does repl.it log undefined at the end?

Tags: javascript, node.js, yaml, markdown, replit

I created [this repl.it](https://repl.it/@OleErsoy/yaml) demo for demonstrating how to parse yaml front matter from a markdown document.

It seems to be working fine, however repl.it logs `=> undefined` at the end and I'm just wondering why it's doing that?

### Update

Per the helpful comment I updated the demo to have this as the last statement:

```
  fs.readFileSync('./test.md');
```

And now that is the last thing logged.

Comment: Ah - That makes sense.  Do you just want to make that the answer?

Comment: I updated the demo with a call to fs.readFileSync('./test.md');  And now that is the last thing that gets logged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your last statement (`console.log("other stuff")`) doesn't return anything, which hence becomes `undefined`. You will notice the same thing happening if you type `console.log("Other Stuff")` into a browser console, because it evaluates the last statement in a block. If you put in a statement that returns something, it will show whatever that statement returns instead